# Dynamic Radio Button PHP

Tags: php, radio-button

I am currently creating an online quiz. In order for me to retrieve information from the input, I think I am required to input a value for the radio button. I wish to input the values as 1 for the first, 2 for the second etc. Since I have used this echo in php, I am assuming it has to be some sort of variable?

I have tried different loop but I can't seem to get it working. Sorry if this sounds like an easy question. Any help would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <title>Online Quiz</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">  
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="" method="post" id="quiz">
            <?php
            require'./quizData.php';
            include('Header.php');

            foreach ($quizSGHistoryQ as $questionNo => $questionInfo) {
                echo "<br>" . $questionNo . ")";
                echo $questionInfo['question'];
                echo $questionInfo['answer'] . "<br>";
                foreach ($questionInfo['options'] as $option => $desc) {
                        echo "<input type= 'radio' name = " . $questionNo  .      " >" . $desc . "<br>";
                }
            }
            include('Footer.php');
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
       </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    foreach ($quizSGHistoryQ as $questionNo => $questionInfo) {
        $pickedAns = $_POST [$questionNo];
        $totalScore = 0;
        if ($pickedAns == $questionInfo['answer']) {
           $totalScore++;
        }
    }
    ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed your code as follow:

```
foreach ($questionInfo['options'] as $option => $desc) 
{
   $key++;
   echo "<input value='".$key."' type= 'radio' name = " . $questionNo  .      " >" . $desc . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: @YennTan so did my answer helped you?